# PostgreSQL not using index on a filtered multiple sort query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, indexing, postgresql-performance

I have a pretty simple table

```
CREATE TABLE approved_posts (
  project_id INTEGER,
  feed_id INTEGER,
  post_id INTEGER,
  approved_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  post_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (project_id, feed_id, post_id)
)
```

And I'm trying to optimize this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM approved_posts
WHERE feed_id IN (?, ?, ?)
AND project_id = ?
ORDER BY approved_time DESC, post_time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The query optimizer is fetching every single `approved_post` that matches the predicate, sorting all 100k results, and returning the top one it finds.

I do have an index on `project_id, feed_id, approved_time, post_time`, which it will use if I either:
**A.** remove the sort by `post_time`, or
**B.** replace the `IN (?, ?, ?)` with a single `= ?`.
Then it simply does a reverse index scan to get the first result and its blazingly fast.

Option **A:**

```
 Limit  (cost=0.43..6.57 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.101..0.101 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using approved_posts_approved_time_idx on approved_posts p  (cost=0.43..840483.02 rows=136940 width=24) (actual time=0.100..0.100 rows=1 loops=1)
     Filter: (feed_id = ANY ('{73321,73771,73772,73773,73774}'::integer[]))
     Rows Removed by Filter: 37
 Total runtime: 0.129 ms
```

Option **B:**

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..3.31 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.065..0.065 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using approved_posts_full_pagination_index on approved_posts p  (cost=0.43..126884.70 rows=44049 width=24) (actual time=0.063..0.063 rows=1 loops=1)
     Index Cond: ((project_id = 148772) AND (feed_id = 73321))
 Total runtime: 0.092 ms
```

But without these tweaks it is not so performant ...

```
Limit  (cost=169792.16..169792.17 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=510.225..510.225 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=169792.16..170118.06 rows=130357 width=24) (actual time=510.224..510.224 rows=1 loops=1)
     Sort Key: approved_time, post_time
     Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on approved_posts p  (cost=12324.41..169140.38 rows=130357 width=24) (actual time=362.210..469.387 rows=126260 loops=1)
           Recheck Cond: (feed_id = ANY ('{73321,73771,73772,73773,73774}'::integer[]))
           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on approved_posts_feed_id_idx  (cost=0.00..12291.82 rows=130357 width=0) (actual time=354.496..354.496 rows=126260 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: (feed_id = ANY ('{73321,73771,73772,73773,73774}'::integer[]))
Total runtime: 510.265 ms
```

I can even add a conditional index on these 5 feed ids and it will once again do the right thing.

My current best solution is to put every `feed_id` in its own query and do a massive `UNION` between them all. But this doesn't scale very well as I might want to select the top 500 from 30 feeds, pulling in 15k rows and sorting them for no good reason. Also managing offsets with this strategy is somewhat complex.

Does anybody know how I can do this `IN` clause with two sorts on my well-indexed data and get Postgres to do the right thing?

I'm using Postgres **9.3.3**. Here are my **indexes**:

```
 "approved_posts_project_id_feed_id_post_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (project_id, feed_id, post_id)
 "approved_posts_approved_time_idx" btree (approved_time)
 "approved_posts_feed_id_idx" btree (feed_id)
 "approved_posts_full_pagination_index" btree (project_id, feed_id, approved_time, post_time)
 "approved_posts_post_id_idx" btree (post_id)
 "approved_posts_post_time_idx" btree (post_time)
 "approved_posts_project_id_idx" btree (project_id)
```

None of the columns are nullable.

This table has 2m rows, split among 200 feed IDs and 19 project IDs.

These are the most common feed IDs:

```
 feed_id | count  
---------+--------
   73607 | 558860
   73837 | 354018
   73832 | 220285
   73836 | 172664
   73321 | 118695
   73819 |  95999
   73821 |  75871
   73056 |  65779
   73070 |  54655
   73827 |  43710
   73079 |  36700
   73574 |  36111
   73055 |  25682
   73072 |  22596
   73589 |  19856
   73953 |  15286
   73159 |  13059
   73839 |   8925
```

In terms of min/max/avg cardinality per `feedid`/`projectid` pairing, we have:

```
 min |  max   |          avg          
-----+--------+-----------------------
   1 | 559021 | 9427.9140271493212670
```

Comment: `9.3.3` begs the question: Why not at least 9.3.9 (if 9.4 is not an option)?. [We always recommend that all users run the latest available minor release for whatever major version is in use.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Comment: We will take a look at upgrading as per your suggestion

Comment: You provided all the necessary details, which allowed me to find answers to your interesting questions. Many questions fail to provide the basics, which is a constant nuisance here - and makes your question shine in this respect now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a list of possible values for `feed_id`, Postgres has a hard time to find the best query plan. Each `feed_id` could be associated with 1 - 559021 rows (according to your numbers). Postgres is not currently smart enough to see the potential optimization for the special case of `LIMIT 1` on its own. A `UNION ALL` (not just `UNION`) of several queries with one `feed_id` and `LIMIT 1` each, plus another outer `LIMIT 1` (like you seem to have tried) demonstrates the potential, but requires sophisticated query concatenation for a variable number of input values.

There is another way to convince the query planner it can use *index scans* to pick the first row from the index for each `feed_id`: rewrite your query with a **`LATERAL`** join:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   (VALUES (?), (?), (?)) AS t(feed_id)
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   approved_posts
   WHERE  project_id = ?
   AND    feed_id = t.feed_id
   ORDER  BY approved_time DESC, post_time DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) a
ORDER  BY approved_time DESC, post_time DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

Or, more convenient for a variable number of values for `feed_id`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   unnest(?) AS t(feed_id)  -- provide int[] var
     , LATERAL ( ...
```

Pass an integer array for the variable, like `'{123, 234, 345}'::int[]`. This could also be implemented elegantly with a function using a **`VARIADIC`** parameter. Then you can pass a list of `integer` values:

- [Pass multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202832/pass-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/19204560#19204560)

Your index on `(project_id, feed_id, approved_time, post_time)` works for this since Postgres can scan indexes backwards almost as fast as forwards, but `(project_id, feed_id, approved_time DESC, post_time DESC)` would be even better. See:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns/39599#39599)

If you don't need to return all columns of the table, even index-only scans might be an option.

Your columns `approved_time`, `post_time` are defined `NOT NULL`. Else, you have to do more:

- [Unused index in range of dates query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/90183/3684)

Related answer detailing the `LATERAL` join technique:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

#### Why did your option A work?

A closer look reveals **two things**:

```
->  Index Scan Backward using approved_posts_approved_time_idx
    on approved_posts p (cost=0.43..840483.02 rows=136940 width=24)
                        (actual time=0.100..0.100 rows=1 loops=1)
     Filter: (feed_id = ANY ('{73321,73771,73772,73773,73774}'::integer[]))
```

Bold emphasis mine.

1. A different, smaller index on just `(approved_time)` is used.
2. There is no *index condition* on `feed_id` (which would not be possible in this case), but a *Filter*.

Postgres chooses a **completely different strategy**: it reads rows from this index bottom-up (`Index Scan Backward`) until it finds a row matching one of your given values for `feed_id`. Since you only have very few projects and feeds (`200 feed IDs and 19 project IDs`), chances are it won't have to discard too many rows before the first match - which is the result. This actually gets ***faster*** with *more* values for `feed_id`, because the "latest" row is found earlier - unlike my first approach which is faster for *fewer* values.

A promising alternative strategy! Depending on data distribution and the feeds in your query it may be faster than my first solution - **enable it with this index**:

```
"approved_posts_foo_idx" btree (project_id, approved_time DESC, post_time DESC)
```

It may pay to selectively increase the statistics targets for the columns `project_id` and `feed_id` so the tipping point between both strategies can be estimated more accurately.

- [Postgresql - Query running a lot faster with enable_nestloop=false. Why is the planner not doing the right thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885129/postgresql-query-running-a-lot-faster-with-enable-nestloop-false-why-is-the-p/7886075#7886075)

---

Since you have projects with only old rows ([as per comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987716/postgresql-not-using-index-on-a-filtered-multiple-sort-query/30991775?noredirect=1#comment50135353_30991775)), you might improve this query with a hint as to the maximum `approved_time` (and `post_time`, but that's probably not adding much) - ***if*** you *know* the maximum `approved_time` per project (and / or per `feed_id`), or at least an upper bound.

```
SELECT ...
WHERE  ...
AND   approved_time <= $upper_bound
```

Comment: This is by far the most elegant way to teach postgres which index to use, and will be much easier to adapt to in our query builder! And its good to know that the huge range of values is where postgres goes wrong.

Comment: A question occurred to me this morning: if the fundamental problem is that there are as few as 1 entries per feed id, then how come when we drop the secondary sort (and only sort by approved_time DESC) it chooses a reverse index scan without requiring any other changes? Edit: In fact, come to think of it, since ordering by approved_time only does a reverse index scan of (approved_time, post_time) it actually already returns the data in approved_time DESC, post_time DESC order. Why in the world would postgres change its plan once we simply ask for it in the order it already has given it to us?

Comment: @MikeFairhurst: Excellent question, I was puzzled by this tipping point myself - until I had a closer look at your `EXPLAIN` output. Consider the addendum to my answer.

Comment: Excellent! Your proposed index works, no query rewrites required! Thank you again!

Comment: @MikeFairhurst: I would be interested which solution performs better for the given test case with 3 `feed_id` (of medium frequency) I would expect `LATERAL` to be faster in this case.

Comment: My data is very temporal...I first ran with three small feed_ids, but got faster results without the lateral. I then noticed that the project_id was newer than the data I showed last; so I found the oldest project and compared its data. In the oldest case, it took 297ms compared to 0.12ms with the lateral

Comment: @MikeFairhurst: You might improve performance of the second query for old projects by providing an upper bound for the timeststamp. Also, increasing the statistics target might help some (like already mentioned). Consider the addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, if the first "where" isn't the first part of the key, the key will not be used. Try switching the order of your "where's" in your query to project_id and feed_id.

Comment: Still no luck! Thanks though. I've been swapping DESCs to ASCs and posttime/approvedtime but haven't thought to swap the WHERE conditions. Definitely was worth a try!